# Display tooltip for invisible series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display a custom tooltip using Highcharts. You can find an example of the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/fDNh9/188/

When you hover over the chart, you can see that the tooltip only contains values from Series 2, but not from Series 1 (which is invisible). When you click on "Series 1" in the legend, you can see the values from Series 1 in the tooltip.

EDIT: no `code` to commit, just fixing linkrot/adhering to editing rules...
Is there any way to display the values from an invisible series in a tooltip?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
        var chart = this.points[0].series.chart; //get the chart object
        var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories; //get the categories array
        var index = 0;
        while(this.x !== categories[index]){index++;} //compute the index of corr y value in each data arrays           
        $.each(chart.series, function(i, series) { //loop through series array
            s += '<br/>'+ series.name +': ' +
                series.data[index].y +'m';     //use index to get the y value
        });           
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks, accepting this solution because I can work on the built-in data arrays from Highcharts.

Comment: Yes, and if you read the chart from `this.point` as well as `this.points` it will work for non-shared tooltips as well

Comment: @BheshGurung is there any way to accomplish this without using categories array? I need to show the minor ticks on the graph as well, but am not able to show them as I am using category for the xAxis. Please reply soon.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore using the latest Highcharts: when the `$.each` iterator hits the hidden series, `series.data` is an empty array.

Comment: you can save the while loop by using:  
var index = categories.indexOf(this.x);

Answer (score 4):

The tooltip formatter is a function like any other function so if you just make the data available it can return a string with values for all series. In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fDNh9/2/) I moved the series arrays and categories to separate variables and the tooltip formatter uses an index into these arrays to find the values.

```
formatter: function() {
    var index = $.inArray(this.x, categories);
    var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

    s += '<br/>'+ chart.series[0].name + ': ' + data1[index];
    s += '<br/>'+ chart.series[1].name + ': ' + data2[index];

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go about this is to make certain attributes of the series invisible, rather than the entire series itself. This will allow you to see it in the tooltip and legend.

Here's what I did:

1. First, I set the line color of the invisible series to "transparent."
2. Next, I set the fill color for the invisible series markers to "transparent."
3. Finally, I disabled the hover state for the markers. This prevents the shadowy highlight circles from appearing as you move your mouse cursor over each point in the visible series.

Here's a modified version of your original fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/fDNh9/184/

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    lineColor: 'transparent',       // make the line invisible
    marker: { 
        fillColor: 'transparent',   // make the line markers invisible
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false      // prevent the highlight circle on hover
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
}]
```

Two items to note:

1. I've used the attribute `enableMouseTracking: false` with other invisible series to prevent users from interacting with them (to achieve visual effects). If you set this for your invisible series, it will prevent the series data from appearing in your tooltip.
2. If you wanted to keep your invisbile series from appearing in the legend, you can add the attribute `showInLegend: false`. Its data will still show in the tooltip.

I hope this helps others who come across this question.

Comment: I assume this will make Highcharts still "draw" the invisible series, and thus factor in the highs and lows and such when drawing the "remaining" visible series. Which is probably not what you want (you instead want the chart to focus on the series which are visible).

Comment: @stolsvik That's a valid point, especially if the invisible series has outlier data that would force minimum or maximum axis values well beyond the visible series. This Stack Overflow question has a custom-built answer that may alleviate that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412442/highcharts-how-to-exempt-a-series-from-redraw-zoom-calculations

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the answer but this is what I did. Plot the chart and make the color transparent. Plotted it on the opposite y axis and set max to zero. Set alignTicks to false. Something like this.

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false,
        type: 'line'
    },
```

Then the only thing needed is to change the color value in tooltip formatter since the label will be transparent.

Hope this helps someone.

Happy Learning :)