# Tooltip doesn't show values if the graph is "off chart"

Tags: highcharts

I have a line graph with several series. The tooltip nicely shows all the values when I hover. However, if one of the series' values result in the drawing of that series's graph going outside the drawing area ("off chart"), the value for that series inside the tooltip also disappears.

I find this very counter productive: I've scaled the Y-axis values so that I get the main variability of the values, and the few extremes are nicely showing as being "off chart". But I would expect to see what the value is from the tooltip when I hover there, i.e. how far is this extreme really above the rest here, numerically.

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wgpnhuyg Note how only the values that are visible are in the tooltip, and when there is no values visible, the tooltip "snaps" to the nearest with value.

Since StackOverflow strangely requires some code to accept a fiddle, here's the y-axis restriction to force the values to go off-chart:

```
min: 5,
max: 15,
```

Comment: Hi, Could you post live example of your issue?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557533/display-tooltip-for-invisible-series-in-highcharts

Comment: Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wgpnhuyg/
Note how only the values that are visible are in the tooltip, and when there is no values visible, the tooltip "snaps" to the nearest with value. Utterly counterintuitive - I mean, there ARE values there, they're just off-chart!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force Highstock to show tooltip for point's outside visible in plot area range you could override default prototype property `directTouch` of Series object like that:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.directTouch = true;
```

You might want to disable [hover state for markers](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.marker.states.hover.enabled) since a halo will show outside plot area.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p1uu05Lv/